# How to configure .NET's WebBrowser to obey the current language settings

Tags: .net, winforms

I am using the System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser object for displaying and printing a report. Unfortunately the Page Setup dialog is not obeying the language settings on the user's computer and all of the text is coming up in English. The .NET dialogs for opening and saving a file are coming up in the correct language but not the Printing/Page Setup dialogs for the Web Browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use threading to set the culture for a particular process.

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("en-US")
```